# Removing matlab version checking code

Tags: matlab, octave

I recently downloaded some code from matlab site to run it with octave. When I try to run a test.m file created by me that calls several functions from the downloaded source code files I receive:

> octave:2> test
>
> error: `verLessThan' undefined near line 101 column 8
>
> error: called from:
>
> error:   /media/34GB/escola/efficientLBP/assignUserInputs.m at line 101, column 5
>
> error:   /media/34GB/escola/efficientLBP/efficientLBP.m at line 113, column 1
>
> error:   /media/34GB/escola/efficientLBP/test.m at line 5, column 7

checking the source file I found this code

```
    if isempty(funcParamsNames)
       isNoFuncParamsNames=true;
    else
       if verLessThan('matlab', '7.14') % again, old version do not support 'stable'. 
          funcParamsNames=unique(funcParamsNames); % This can lead to bugs :(
       else
          funcParamsNames=unique(funcParamsNames , 'stable');
       end%
       isNoFuncParamsNames=false;
    end
```

So I was wondering  if there is a way to make octave to recognizance this function. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Octave's `unique` is like Matlab's `unique(...,'sorted')`, not like `unique(...,'stable')`, as you can see [here](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@1@al1lYmqoRbaxgpADChrGa//8DAA).If you need a `'stable'` for version Octave check [this](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/blob/master/compatibility/unique_comp.m)

Answer (score 0):

Octave seems to know an equivalent function [`unique`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/unique.html), however, I see no option like Matlabs `'stable'`.

Try unique and see what it does I guess?

```
if isempty(funcParamsNames)
   isNoFuncParamsNames=true;
else
   funcParamsNames=unique(funcParamsNames);       
   isNoFuncParamsNames=false;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do `unique` with `'stable'` yourself:

```
x = rand(1,10);x(5) = x(1);
% if you have 'stable'
y1 = unique(x,'stable');
% if you don't have 'stable'
[y2,ia] = unique(x);
[ia,idxs] = sort(ia);
y2 = y2(idxs);
% compare
isequal(y1,y2)
```